# Variable Explorer not showing plots in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I just started with Python and installed WinPython and Spyder. The Variable Explorer is great but I cannot make it show any plots (Plot, Show Image, Histogram). Nothing happens when I select those options after choosing an array or any other type of variable.

I can get plots to show using the Console or runnin a script. However, the plt.plot() command by itself does not make a plot window to show up. I have to execute plt.show() to get the window to be created.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

FS

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder dev here*) Unfortunately it seems that our plotting facilities for the Variable Explorer are not working correctly (as you discovered).

If you are using an IPython Console, they don't work at all whereas with a regular Console you need to hit *Enter* several times (two or three) to make the plot appear.

I opened an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1475) for you in our Issue tracker and we'll try to fix it in one of our next releases.